# Redirect Loop to Page, Can't Find Origin, Can't Remove

Tags: loop, permalinks, redirect, htaccess, errors

I have a new client who did "something, I can't remember what" to her blog.  Now when you visit the home page, it redirects to a page she created and deleted, "/road-maps/".  I have no idea why it started doing this, or how she got it to do this.  She has no FTP access and did something solely in the Wordpress back office.  I located the deleted page in the trash and deleted it permanently but it still redirects.  I disabled every plugin and it still redirects to there.  I exported the database and looked for instances of "road-maps" anywhere inside it and found only two places - the temporary redirect that I put in place to a static page while I try and fix the problem, and the references to the page in the site tracking logs.  Nothing else.  I looked in .htaccess and it looks fine, no mention of "road-maps".  I SSHed into the site and did a global search for "road-maps" and found nothing.  I'm at my wit's end.  Where could this redirect possibly be coming from?  And how do I remove it?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

You can try a number of things.

1. Delete the `.htaccess` file in the WordPress root directory.
2. Visit: `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks -> Save Changes`
3. Visit: `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays`
   Select an appropriate page. Then click "Save Changes".

You could also read [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85820/9579) to the question ([**How do I redirect a Wordpress Page?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85804/how-do-i-redirect-a-wordpress-page)) posted on WPSE as another possible solution.